# Get the next row from a query

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I've got these data in the DB:

```
ID    col1    col2
32      2      0
31      2      0
76      1      0
12      0      0
10      0      0
25      0      1
20      0      1
28      0      2
```

These data has been obtained from this query:

```
SELECT ID, col1, col2 
FROM tableA
ORDER BY col1 DESC, col2 ASC, ID DESC
```

Once I have and ID/col1 value, I would like to get the next row of this query.
Could it be possible to do it with an only query?

Important information: col1 and col2 can't be both different to zero. If col1 is different to zero, col2 is zero and vice versa.

EDIT:
I'm using MySQL. No API's

Let's say, for example that I have ID: 31. Then I need to get the row with ID 76

If I have the ID 10, then I need the row with ID 25.

Comment: Next row like `LAG/LEAD`? Share desired output

Comment: It is unclear what you ask from the current description.

Comment: How are you accessing the database? What API are you using? Which language?

Comment: Also the given SQL cannot produce that output. The order would have been different.

Comment: @arkascha : is it clear enough now?

Comment: @trincot: stupid error. My mistake. Sorry

Comment: No, not really more clear. What do you mean by "Once I have and ID/col1 value"? Or by "If I have the ID 10". Where do you have it if you are not using some sort of scripting or whatever client logic. But if you have some sort of logic, then what is the problem with fetching the next row?

Comment: @arkascha: I have the ID and col1 values of a single row. Let's say: ID=10 and col1=0. Then, I need to obtain the next row, i.e: row with ID=25

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method, although I do wonder if there is a simpler way:

```
select a.*
from TableA a cross jooin
     (select a.*
      from TableA a
      where id = 31
     ) thea
where thea.col1 < a.col1 or
      thea.col1 = a.col1 and thea.col2 > a.col2 or
      thea.col1 = a.col1 and thea.col2 = a.col2 and thea.id < a.id
order by a.col1 DESC, a.col2 ASC, a.ID DESC
limit 1;
```

EDTI:

A simpler way uses variables:

```
select a.*
from (select a.*,
             (@rn := if(a.id = 31,
                        if(@found := 1, 1, 1),
                        if(@found = 1, @rn + 1, -1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from tablea a cross join
           (select @rn := 0, @found := 0) params
      order by a.col1 DESC, a.col2 ASC, a.ID DESC
     ) a
where rn = 2;
```

Comment: @trincot . . . The OP can put in whatever value s/he wants to.  The question explicitly mentions 31.

Comment: That was given as an example. Check again, the OP mentions another value as second example. The solution needs to be generic.

Comment: @trincot . . . I think anyone reading the answer can figure out how to put a parameter in for "31".  The OP doesn't mention how values are passed in to his/her query, so this seems sufficient.